# Configure routes.rb for Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just moved to using Rails 3.0.3 on my Mac OS X.

When i tried to generate controllers and views as follows:

```
 $rails generate controller testing
```

it created the controller at the appropriate place. i created a method/action in the same controller called `greet` and when i tried to access this via the browser at:

```
 http://localhost:3000/testing/greet
```

It gave me an error saying:

```
 Routing Error

 No route matches "/testing/greet"
```

But if i add the following line in my `routes.rb` file:

```
 get 'testing#greet'
```

it works fine, But, i cannot add the above line for each and every method in my application.

Please help me on how to rectify this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's not over complicating.

Assuming testing is resoucedful, in routes:

```
resources :testings do
  # for individual /testing/1/greet
  member do
    get 'greet'
  end

  # on the collection
  collection do
    get 'greet'
  end
end
```

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "every route needs defined"

Comment: Thanks Seth for your answer, but i believe if i keep on defining every route in my routes.rb file then i'll over complicate the things and my routes.rb file will not look good. anyways, thanks for your answer. I figured this one out and will post the answer shortly.

Comment: I look back at this question and feel so naive :) Fast-forward 2 years - I'm a Pro at Rails and Ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating routing. Please read the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for enlightenment.

Comment: I'm sorry if i over complicated the things, but the answer requires this one simple line in `routes.rb` file to work: `match ':controller/:action'`

Answer (score -1):

If you are coming from Rails 2.x to Rails 3.0, your `routes.rb` file is probably missing this line:

```
 match ':controller/:action'
```

In Rails 2.x this line was:

```
 map.connect ':controller/:action'
```

Because of the change in the Routing API and introduction of Action Dispatch you need to add the first line in your routes.rb file to map every method automatically.

PS: Please remember that if you need to overwrite the above routing, you'll need to declare routing commands above this line, because priority in Rails Routing takes bottom down approach.

Thanks!

Comment: This catch-all route is _strongly_ discouraged and is considered deprecated. REST-style routes as detailed at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default are the way to go.

Comment: Hello Brian, that might be the case. But, since i just switched to Rails 3 from Rails 2, I was already missing what i  had in Rails 2. I'm still going through all the guides and API documentation to confirm to Rails 3 standards. But, for now this is exactly what i was looking to test out Rails 3. Now, since that i know it's been deprecated i'll look into the fact what polished version's been introduced in Rails 3 and will start using that in Production. Thanks Again!